# How can I align three divs in this way?

Tags: html, css

There are two columns for three divs. One is floated on the left, the width of which is 60%, containing 1 div (an image). The other is floated on the right, the width of which is 40%, containing two divs. These two divs are vertically aligned, and the height of them equals the height of the image.

I am sorry if I did not make my question clear. It would be better if I can upload a picture here. Thank you in advance! I have tried to achieve this for almost 2 hours, but still failed. I really want to know how to do this.

[image]

Here is the code I have in HTML:

```
<div id = "content" class = "group">
    <img src="image/Home_HeroImg_Vision.jpg" id="bigpic">
    <div id = "col">
      <div id = "p1">
        <h2 class="para">upcoming events</h2>
        <img src="image/RightArrow.png" class = "arrow">
        <img src="image/BirdSmall.jpg" id = "bird">
        <p id="para1">Paul Shellmont:</p>
        <p id="para2">Bird Watching</p>
        <p id="para3">April 5, 2012 - June 30, 2012</p>
        <a href="www.facebook.com">learn more</a>
      <div>
      <div id="p2">
        <h2 class="para">upcoming events</h2>
        <img src="image/RightArrow.png" class = "arrow">
        <p id="para1">Paul Shellmont:</p>
        <p id="para2">Bird Watching</p>
        <p id="para3">April 5, 2012 - June 30, 2012</p>
        <a href="www.facebook.com">learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code for CSS:

```
#content {
  background: #E4E4E4;
  margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

#content img,
#content div {
  padding: 10px;
}

#bigpic {
  float: left;
    width: 60%;
}

#col{
  float:right;
  width:40%;
}

#p1, #p2 {
  height: 50%
}
```

Comment: Would help if you cost post the code you got so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am so sorry. I did not mean to ask for codes directly. I will post my code soon!

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic layout correct. Your problem lies in your setting of the widths but also adding padding. Remember that `width` is the width of the content. When you add padding, that increases the total width of your element.

For example, your `#bigpic` is set to 60% width but its container also has 10px of padding. That makes its total width 60% plus 20px for both sides of the element.

A way to check that is to just remove the padding for `#bigpic`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! But I use this already,                             * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
} Shouldn't it mean that my padding will not added to the width I set?

Comment: @KabeLee You don't show that in your mark up above. If you aren't showing a complete example, you need to add it now.